# Hadoop: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, macos-sierra, word-count

I'm trying to launch a fairly simple WordCount (I pretty much followed [this tutorial](https://hashnode.com/post/how-i-was-finally-able-to-run-the-infamous-word-count-example-on-hadoop-ciwazrq8u000vgw53qe4saran)) after installing Hadoop but I get this:

```
2018-04-05 16:51:00,192 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1522936330711_0007 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1522936330711_0007 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1522936330711_0007_000002 exited with  exitCode: 1
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2018-04-05 16:50:59.449]Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1522936330711_0007_02_000001
Exit code: 1

[2018-04-05 16:50:59.452]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
Error : Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster


[2018-04-05 16:50:59.452]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
Error : Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster


For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://iMac-de-chaire-2.local:8088/cluster/app/application_1522936330711_0007 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
. Failing the application.
2018-04-05 16:51:00,211 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
```

When I try to access the logs it tells me `"Failed to read the attempts of the application application_1522940117199_0001."`

I have the following files :

`hadoop-env.sh` :

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop/

export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native"
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
```

`yarn-site.xml` :

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.application.classpath</name>
    <value>$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*,$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

`mapred-site.xml` :

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.application.classpath</name>
    <value>$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*,$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

I am on `macosx high-sierra`, and this is the first time I am trying to setup `Hadoop` (I followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@nidhinmahesh/getting-started-hadoop-mapreduce-hdfs-and-yarn-configuration-and-sample-program-febb1415f945)).

Comment: have you try the  hadoop wordcountexample .jar  .

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, also on `macosx high-sierra`. To solve this add these properties to `mapred-site.xml`:

```
<property>
 <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env</name>
 <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>mapreduce.map.env</name>
 <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>mapreduce.reduce.env</name>
 <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME</value>
</property>
```